# Bytes sequence framing

Tags: java, networking, byte, communication

Suppose I get from the network a sequence of bytes in the following order:
X X X X = X X X X = X X X X = ... and so on
you can notice immediately the pattern (a message is a sequence of 5 bytes:  "X X X X =
X can be any number except '=' of course)

Now, the transmission occur periodically.
In some point my application is starting and getting the bytes sequence

**What is the best algorithm for taking those bytes and framing them to 5 bytes messages?**
There are two problems:
1. How do you find the first message? I guess I need to drop some bytes till I get '=' right?
2. How the application suppose to handle a pause of transimmision and a **new start**.

Comment: There is a lot of information missing. What is generating the input? Can it have start byte sequence? Is it null terminated? How do you determine when to stop reading? What does a new start entail (clear a buffer and start reading in again)?

Comment: If you aren't oversimplifying and those really do come 5 bytes at a time, you could try all 5 possible frame positions for the first frame and discard the frames that fail (of course that won't fly if the frame size is much larger). To handle pauses an re-starts you could just restart the process once a mismatch is detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a blocking read (which is the most common because its the simplest) to read 5 bytes at a time.

Normally, you wouldn't assume you have junk data at the start, and just read everything. If you have a header, I would read that too.

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket stream);
byte[] bytes = new byte[5];

int sep;
do {
  dis.readFully(bytes);
  process(bytes);
} while((sep = dis.read()) == '=');
if (sep > 0)
   System.err.println("Unexpected character "+ (char) sep));
```